# Контроль наличия пользователя в локальной сети средствами Python

Tags: python, сеть

Подскажите как можно отслеживать пользователя в локальной сети средствами Python3? Нужно просто узнавать в сети или нет. ОС окошко.

Comment: Периодически пересылать сообщение с хоста на сервер: "host имя в сети"

Comment: Может поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207234/list-of-ip-addresses-hostnames-from-local-network-in-python